# poetry install - ConnectionError | Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'

Tags: python-3.x, connection, connection-pooling, urllib3, python-poetry

I am using `Poetry version 1.1.7`.

Running `poetry install` yields this error.

Can this be resolved through bash or is this explicitly to do with my network? Note: Internet connectivity it perfectly fine in browsers.

```sh
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/workers-python/workers/CompositeKey/CompositeKey$ poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (225.5s)

  ConnectionError

  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pkgs.dev.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <CENSORED> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f53950c3ee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/requests/adapters.py:516 in send
      512│             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
      513│                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
      514│                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
      515│ 
    → 516│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      517│ 
      518│         except ClosedPoolError as e:
      519│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      520│
```

---

A `401 Unauthorized Error` is thrown when pasting the URL into my browser.

Comment: have you set poetry to look for packages somewhere other than PyPI? cause it looks like its trying to connect to a private Azure package dist

Comment: Looks like a network error `Network is unreachable`. If you meant to install from that azure server (`poetry config --list`, [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/)), make sure you resolve any network issues. Either you're blocked from reaching this destination (corporate VPN?) or your local settings (`iptables`, corporate policies) are blocking you.

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe Yes, I did `export POETRY_REPOSITORIES_AZURE_URL="my_url"` intentionally. I have every other time for work

Comment: A **401 Unauthorized Error** is thrown when pasting the URL into my browser.

Comment: Sometimes it happens because of internet issues and next time it can run successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did:

- `poetry self update 1.0.10`
- `poetry install`

Terminal is giving me installs now, as it should.

```sh
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/workers-python/workers/CompositeKey/CompositeKey$ poetry self update 1.0.10
Updating to 1.0.10
 - Downloading poetry-1.0.10-linux.tar.gz 100%

Poetry (1.0.10) is installed now. Great!
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/workers-python/workers/CompositeKey/CompositeKey$ poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (101.5s)

Writing lock file


Package operations: 167 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing six (1.16.0)
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and it turns out to be connection refused by server due to  exceeding the max connections limit of the mirror repo.

By default `poetry`'s max `installer.max-workers` is set to `number_of_cores + 4`. This would be a problem when you run poetry on a server with like 24 cores and it is reasonable for the server side to refuse that many of connections.

The work around is to config this value manually before executing `poetry install`, you can use the following command to do limit the max connections:

```bash
poetry config installer.max-workers 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody here is looking for this problem solution:

```bash
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa0c6e47510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out')'
```

You may try to change `poetry` version to `1.1.8` and add settings to `pyproject.toml`:

```yaml
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=1.1.1", "setuptools", "cython"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```