# I am getting no module name cleo when trying to do "poetry add"

Tags: django, python-poetry

I have completely uninstalled and re installed poetry using:

```
POETRY_UNINSTALL=1 bash -c 'curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python'
```

then I re installed it using:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
```

but it did not fix the issue. and then I # for poetry config

```
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to re-install poetry

```bash
# install
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
# update
poetry self update
# uninstall
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
```

Comment: That's a good one! I was having this issue and by running the last command to uninstall, it actually fixed it. I didn't need to reinstall, but it's now working

Comment: get-poetry.sh was deprecated for some time and doesn't exist anymore under the link provided here

Answer (score 5):

This command fixed it for me (OSX):

```
rm -rf ~/.poetry
```

I think it gets your local files in a muddle!

Be careful running this in your user folder!

Answer (score 4):

To add to this, I am using `zsh` on WSL and I had to:

#### Uninstall poetry

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
```

#### Remove poetry executables (I used `which poetry` to find these)

```
rm /home/<username>/.local/bin/poetry

sudo rm /usr/bin/poetry
```

#### Reinstall poetry

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

#### Export PATH to shell config

```
# Open .zshrc
nano ~/.zshrc
# Add 'export PATH="/home/tristannew/.local/bin:$PATH"' to file
# Reload zsh
source ~/.zshrc
```

#### Finally, check poetry version

```
poetry --version
```

This worked for me so I am posting it here in case the other people require the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a combination of the existing answers to get it working

```
# uninstall poetry
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall

# remove the existing poetry cache(?) from your home directory
rm -rf /home/<username>/.poetry

# reinstall poetry
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

See this [Github issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3345#issuecomment-1017921998) for more info

Comment: this was the only working solution for me

Answer (score -2):

`poetry self update 1.0.10` then `poetry install`.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68680055/poetry-install-connectionerror-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection-errno). Two separate errors, both caused by poetry version.

Comment: I need to install poetry using curl because I am using bash. https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation

Comment: when I attempted the above I got no module name cleo again.