# Unable to install poetry in dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, python-poetry

I am getting this error when running any poetry executables

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/bin/poetry", line 5, in <module>
    from poetry.console.application import main
  File "/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/console/application.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cleo.application import Application as BaseApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleo'
```

My container is built using this logic.

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python38-template-launcher-base:flex_templates_base_image_release_20230508_RC00
ARG DIR=/dataflow/template
ARG dataflow_file_path
ARG PROJECT_ID
# environment to pull the right containers
ARG ENV
ARG TOKEN
ENV COMPOSER_$ENV=1

# copying over necessary files
RUN mkdir -p ${DIR}
WORKDIR ${DIR}
COPY transform/dataflow/${dataflow_file_path}.py beam.py
COPY deploy/dataflow/poetry.lock .
COPY deploy/dataflow/pyproject.toml .

# env var in order to use custom lib, for more info, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#set_required_dockerfile_environment_variables
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${DIR}/beam.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES=""
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS=""
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True

# install poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python -
ENV PATH "/root/.local/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN poetry --version
```

I have tried uninstalling it and the suggestions from:

- https://medium.com/@life-is-short-so-enjoy-it/python-poetry-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cleo-1f924239b06c
- [I am getting no module name cleo when trying to do "poetry add"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950213/i-am-getting-no-module-name-cleo-when-trying-to-do-poetry-add)
- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3071
- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2991

These aren't really applicable because they are `poetry` executables in a non-docker environment but not really sure what else to do . I have an Dataflow SDK that was build from `apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.45.0` that has the same logic and it is working.

I disregarded the last `RUN` command and built the container, these are the outputs of some checks

```
❯ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash dataflow -c 'which poetry'
/root/.local/bin/poetry
❯ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash dataflow -c 'poetry'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/bin/poetry", line 5, in <module>
    from poetry.console.application import main
  File "/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/console/application.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cleo.application import Application as BaseApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleo'
❯ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash dataflow -c 'which python'
/usr/local/bin/python
```

My assumption is that the `poetry` executables are importing in a virtualenv that the other libraries aren't installed to.

UPDATE:

I went down a rabbit hole and did this

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir poetry cleo rapidfuzz importlib_metadata zipp crashtest
```

And running `poetry --version` worked but `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` or any other command will throw this error

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/poetry", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/console/application.py", line 409, in main
    exit_code: int = Application().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cleo/application.py", line 338, in run
    self.render_error(e, io)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/console/application.py", line 180, in render_error
    self.set_solution_provider_repository(self._get_solution_provider_repository())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/console/application.py", line 398, in _get_solution_provider_repository
    from poetry.mixology.solutions.providers.python_requirement_solution_provider import (  # noqa: E501
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/mixology/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from poetry.mixology.version_solver import VersionSolver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/mixology/version_solver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from poetry.core.packages.dependency import Dependency
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry.core'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It appears to be the ordering of the `Dockerfile` when building a Dataflow Flex template

This will work

```
# THIS WILL BE MOVED
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH "/root/.local/bin/:${PATH}"

# copying over necessary files
RUN mkdir -p ${DIR}
WORKDIR ${DIR}
COPY transform/dataflow/${dataflow_file_path}.py beam.py
COPY deploy/dataflow/poetry.lock .
COPY deploy/dataflow/pyproject.toml .

# env var in order to use custom lib, for more info, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#set_required_dockerfile_environment_variables
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${DIR}/beam.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES=""
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS=""
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True
```

But this will not

```
# copying over necessary files
RUN mkdir -p ${DIR}
WORKDIR ${DIR}
COPY transform/dataflow/${dataflow_file_path}.py beam.py
COPY deploy/dataflow/poetry.lock .
COPY deploy/dataflow/pyproject.toml .

# env var in order to use custom lib, for more info, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#set_required_dockerfile_environment_variables
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${DIR}/beam.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES=""
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS=""
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True


# THIS MOVED
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH "/root/.local/bin/:${PATH}"
```

Looking a bit deeper, it may be that the environment variables are at play, although I'm not quite *exactly* how. This is the environment variables of when there are errors

This is the `env` of the working image

```
❯ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash dataflow -c 'env'
_=/usr/bin/env
PATH=/root/.local/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/1a96dc5acd0303c4700e02655aefd3bc68c78958/public/get-pip.py
PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=d1d09b0f9e745610657a528689ba3ea44a73bd19c60f4c954271b790c71c2653
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=22.0.4
SHLVL=0
LANG=C.UTF-8
HOME=/root
PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=57.5.0
PWD=/
CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=yes
PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.16
```

This is the `env` output of when it errors out

```
❯ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash dataflow -c 'env'
_=/usr/bin/env
PIP_NO_DEPS=True
PATH=/root/.local/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/1a96dc5acd0303c4700e02655aefd3bc68c78958/public/get-pip.py
PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=d1d09b0f9e745610657a528689ba3ea44a73bd19c60f4c954271b790c71c2653
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=22.0.4
SHLVL=0
FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES=
FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS=
FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE=/dataflow/template/beam.py
LANG=C.UTF-8
HOME=/root
PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=57.5.0
PWD=/dataflow/template
CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=yes
PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.16
```