# ConnectionError HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded url: /pypi/poetry/json [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Tags: python-poetry

Goal: `poetry install`

- Poetry version **1.1.12**
- [pyproject.toml](https://gist.github.com/danielbellhv/4c86f93e2d64556c6a593fcba9e94fd8)

Running `poetry install` gives the same error as below on all the libraries/ dependencies I want to install.

I also cannot uninstall:

```
$ python3 get-poetry.py --uninstall
python3: can't open file 'get-poetry.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(sdg) me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foo/bar$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | POETRY_UNINSTALL=1 python3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
(sdg) me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foor/bar$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | POETRY_UNINSTALL=1 python3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68682019/17840900) did not help.

Terminal:

```
(sdg) me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foo/bar$ poetry
Poetry version 1.1.12

USAGE
  poetry [-h] [-q] [-v [<...>]] [-V] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n] <command> [<arg1>] ... [<argN>]

ARGUMENTS
  <command>              The command to execute
  <arg>                  The arguments of the command

GLOBAL OPTIONS
  -h (--help)            Display this help message
  -q (--quiet)           Do not output any message
  -v (--verbose)         Increase the verbosity of messages: "-v" for normal output, "-vv" for more verbose output and "-vvv" for debug
  -V (--version)         Display this application version
  --ansi                 Force ANSI output
  --no-ansi              Disable ANSI output
  -n (--no-interaction)  Do not ask any interactive question

AVAILABLE COMMANDS
  about                  Shows information about Poetry.
  add                    Adds a new dependency to pyproject.toml.
  build                  Builds a package, as a tarball and a wheel by default.
  cache                  Interact with Poetry's cache
  check                  Checks the validity of the pyproject.toml file.
  config                 Manages configuration settings.
  debug                  Debug various elements of Poetry.
  env                    Interact with Poetry's project environments.
  export                 Exports the lock file to alternative formats.
  help                   Display the manual of a command
  init                   Creates a basic pyproject.toml file in the current directory.
  install                Installs the project dependencies.
  lock                   Locks the project dependencies.
  new                    Creates a new Python project at <path>.
  publish                Publishes a package to a remote repository.
  remove                 Removes a package from the project dependencies.
  run                    Runs a command in the appropriate environment.
  search                 Searches for packages on remote repositories.
  self                   Interact with Poetry directly.
  shell                  Spawns a shell within the virtual environment.
  show                   Shows information about packages.
  update                 Update the dependencies as according to the pyproject.toml file.
  version                Shows the version of the project or bumps it when a valid bump rule is provided.

(sdg) me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foo/bar$ poetry self update 1.0.10

  ConnectionError

  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/poetry/json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f143dd3e7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/requests/adapters.py:516 in send
      512│             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
      513│                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
      514│                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
      515│ 
    → 516│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      517│ 
      518│         except ClosedPoolError as e:
      519│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      520│
```

`$ poetry config --list`:

```
cache-dir = "/home/me/.cache/pypoetry"
experimental.new-installer = true
installer.parallel = true
virtualenvs.create = true
virtualenvs.in-project = null
virtualenvs.path = "{cache-dir}/virtualenvs"  # /home/me/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
```

`$ python -m certifi`:

```
/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```

Comment: [Git Issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5203)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disconnected my VPN and ran:

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | POETRY_UNINSTALL=1 python3
# We are sorry to see you go!

This will uninstall Poetry.

It will remove the `poetry` command from Poetry's bin directory, located at:

$HOME/.poetry/bin

This will also remove Poetry from your system's PATH.
```